# Descomentar lineas con # y un espacio después usando sed

Tags: bash, sed

Estoy intentando eliminar un espacio al principio de una linea. Tengo el siguiente comando que funciona:

```
sed -i "/deb-src/s/^#//g" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/repo.list
```

El problema que tengo es que empieza así:

```
# deb-src [...]
```

La almohadilla sí la borra pero no consigo eliminar ese espacio también.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que añadirle un espacio en el patrón de búsqueda, quedando así:

```
sed -i "/deb-src/s/^# //" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/repo.list
```